# Loading dates from a text file in EPPLUS

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, date, epplus

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet in my web application using a tab-delimited text file as the data source. The code that loads my data looks like this:

```
// Load the data into the cells
Int32 rowIdx = 1;
foreach (String line in tab.Lines)
{
    String[] cellTexts = line.Split(TAB);
    Int32 colIdx = 1;
    foreach (String cellText in cellTexts)
    {
        sheet.Cells[rowIdx, colIdx].Value = cellText;
        colIdx++;
    }
    rowIdx++;
}
```

That seems to work fine. Later, however, I add a NumberFormat of "mm/dd/yyyy" to the cells:

```
range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy";
```

However, this doesn't change the display of the data in the cells. (The dates look like `5/1/15` or `12/31/15` in the original text file, and remain that way after the format is applied.

I am pretty sure that this because I've put a ***text*** value into the cell. (While it **looks** like a date, it's still just a string of characters.) But from my reading, I need to put a ***double*** into the cell to meet Excel's expectation that dates are stored as a double. Because the cell contains a string and not a double, the format string isn't applied, leaving the original, unformatted text.

I want to add some code to

1. Check the type of data in each cell in the range to which I apply a
   date format.
2. If it's not a double, attempt to convert it to a date.
3. If the date conversion is successful, then convert the .NET date to an OADate and put it back into the cell.

My question is: **Is this the best (or at least a reasonable) approach, and if so, how do I do that?**

This code doesn't work:

```
foreach (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase oneCell in range)
{
    if (typeof(oneCell.Value) == "System.String")
    {
        // date manipulations here
    }
}
```

The red line appears under `oneCell` in the `typeof(oneCell.Value)` call with the message "**The type or namespace 'oneCell' could not be found. (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

Note that I can't know in advance where the date fields will be because both the data and the cell formats are provided from an external source. (The external cell formats do indicate when the format being applied is for a date format as opposed to a regular number format or a string.)

Comment: I believe you can assign a `DateTime` to a cell's Value directly. So then it's just a matter of parsing your input into a DateTime object rather than a double.

Comment: I went a different way by adding a DateTime.TryParse() to the loop that initially loads the cell data into the sheet. Basically, if it looks like a date, treat it like a date. (I did the same with Double.TryParse() for numeric values.) It's not 100%, but it's good enough for my current needs. Also, I did NOT have to convert the DateTime to an OADate, as you noted.

Comment: You should post your resulting code as an answer, to help future people with similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mason suggested, I'm posting the code I used to get around this problem.

(I didn't get an answer to my original question, which is how to iterate cells in a range and check the data type of each cell's content, but with this solution, I no longer need to do that.)

Instead, I modified the loop that loads the data from the tab-delimited text file to use some `TryParse()` calls to detect dates, numbers, or regular text data, and then load the appropriately typed data into the cell. Note how it checks for a leading single quote character to suppress the data typing if the cell is actually text, but ***looks*** like a number or a date:

```
// Load the data into the cells
Int32 rowIdx = 1;
foreach (String line in tab.Lines)
{
    String[] cellTexts = line.Split(TAB);
    Int32 colIdx = 1;
    foreach (String cellText in cellTexts)
    {
        DateTime dateValue;
        Double doubleValue;
        if(cellText.StartsWith("'"))
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIdx, colIdx].Value = cellText.Substring(1);
        }
        else if(DateTime.TryParse(cellText,out dateValue))
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIdx, colIdx].Value = dateValue;
        }
        else if (Double.TryParse(cellText, out doubleValue))
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIdx, colIdx].Value = doubleValue;
        }
        else
        {
            sheet.Cells[rowIdx, colIdx].Value = cellText;
        }
        colIdx++;
    }
    rowIdx++;
}
```

With the data typed appropriately in the cells, the formats have the desired effect.